# Trying to program

Tags: java

I´m trying to program a tokenizer, which has a String as input for example "   34   56  7899 "
and should edit the single tokens "34"  "56"  and "7899". Moreover I'm not allowed to use the standard java tokenizer or the string method "split". The method next() should have the next token as an output or if there is no token anymore it should return null.
Here is my code of the next() method:

```java
public String next() {
    int counter1=0;
    int counter2=0;

    for(int i=0;i<token.length();i++) {
        counter1++;
        if((int)token.charAt(i)!=32) {
            for(int j=counter1;j<token.length();j++) {
                if((int)token.charAt(j)!=32) {
                    counter2++;
                }
                else if((int)token.charAt(j)==32||i+counter2==token.length()-1) {
                    ergebnis=token.substring(i, i+counter2);
                    token.replaceAll(token.substring(i, i+counter2)," ");
                    return ergebnis;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ergebnis;
}
```

The problem is that if I run this method in my main class, it doesn't edit the token but it I also don't receive an error message, so I don't know why this isn't working.

I would be very grateful if you could help me with my problem.

Comment: What does this mean, "it doesn't edit the token"?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post the code that calls method `next()` as well as what is returned? I assume that the method is not returning what you want it to return, so also post what you want the method to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
public class Tokenizer
{
    private String str;
    private char delimeter;
    private int pos;

    public Tokenizer(String str, char delimeter)
    {
        this.str = str;
        this.delimeter = delimeter;
    }

    public String next()
    {
        // consume delimeters
        while(pos < str.length() && str.charAt(pos) == delimeter) pos++;

        // if we're at the end of the string there are no more tokens
        if(pos == str.length()) return null;

        // record the start position of the next token
        int tokenStart = pos;

        // consume non-delimeter characters
        while(pos < str.length() && str.charAt(pos) != delimeter) pos++;

        // pos is now one past the end of the next token, or the end of the string
        return str.substring(tokenStart, pos);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
Tokenizer t = new Tokenizer(" 34 56 7899 ", ' ');

String tk;
while((tk = t.next()) != null) 
    System.out.format("Token <%s>%n", tk);
```

Output:

```
Token <34>
Token <56>
Token <7899>
```

Answer (score 1):

See, if you are looking for something like this.

First, Write a CustomTokenizer, something like below -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomTokenizer {

    private String input;
    private String delimiter;
    private List<String> tokensList;

    public CustomTokenizer(String input, String delimiter){
        this.input = input;
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    public void tokenize(){
        if(input == null || delimiter == null){
            return ;
        }
        tokensList = new ArrayList<>();
        while(!input.isEmpty()){

            // find the first index of delimiter
            int indexOfDelimiter = input.indexOf(delimiter);

            // delimiter may not be present for the last element, so indexOf() returns -1
            if(indexOfDelimiter == -1){
                // adding the last token to the arrayList
                tokensList.add(input);

                // Doing a substring from string length so that it becomes empty
                input = input.substring(input.length());
            } else {
                // Doing a substring from index 0 till the indexOf delimiter
                String temp = input.substring(0, indexOfDelimiter);
                if(!temp.isEmpty()){
                    tokensList.add(temp);
                }

                // Doing a substring from the first indexOf delimiter till the last of the string
                input = input.substring(indexOfDelimiter+1);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return !tokensList.isEmpty();
    }

    public String next(){
        if(tokensList.isEmpty())
            return null;
        return tokensList.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Then write the Driver Class -

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Pass the input string and delimiter to the CustomTokenizer Constructor
        CustomTokenizer ct = new CustomTokenizer(" 34 56 7899 ", " ");

        // calling the tokenize method to separate the tokens
        ct.tokenize();

        while(ct.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(ct.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

> 34
>   56
>   7899